# X11 not available?

Tags: ubuntu, x11, qemu

I'm trying to use `qemu`, but whenever I try to start it, I get this error message:

```
[x86-64-debug] me:~/fuchsia$ frun -g
+ echo CMDLINE: TERM=xterm-256color kernel.entropy-mixin=540cde8490a5d80fdb709ff7dcbf6094d92a40dc7d9cfed901758756a666e9dc kernel.halt-on-panic=true
CMDLINE: TERM=xterm-256color kernel.entropy-mixin=540cde8490a5d80fdb709ff7dcbf6094d92a40dc7d9cfed901758756a666e9dc kernel.halt-on-panic=true
+ exec /home/colton/androidstuff/fuchsia/buildtools/linux-x64/qemu/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2048 -serial stdio -vga std -net none -smp 4,threads=2 -machine q35 -kernel /home/colton/androidstuff/fuchsia/out/build-zircon/build-zircon-pc-x86-64/zircon.bin -cpu Haswell,+smap,-check -initrd /home/colton/androidstuff/fuchsia/out/debug-x86-64/user.bootfs -append 'TERM=xterm-256color kernel.entropy-mixin=540cde8490a5d80fdb709ff7dcbf6094d92a40dc7d9cfed901758756a666e9dc kernel.halt-on-panic=true '
Could not initialize SDL(x11 not available) - exiting`
```

(I'm trying to build Google's Fuchsia repository)

I've already looked around, but nothing has worked (most people get a display unavailable error message or they run into this problem in `R`).

I'm running Ubuntu Budgie

Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Comment: Are you following these instructions:  [googlesource Fuchsia Getting Started](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/docs/+/master/getting_started.md)

Comment: @RubberStamp Yes I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the Linux kernel is starting to move towards Wayland, rather than X11, starting with 17.10. Because of this, `qemu` won't work well anymore.

Comment: You mean, Linux *distributions* are moving towards Wayland. The kernel itself is totally GUI agnostic. And nothing prevents you from running an X server even on distros which default to Wayland. Also, SDL (look at the error message) doesn't even need X (if you configure it properly).

Comment: @dirkt right. Still learning a bit. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @dirkt any resources for configuring sdl to not need x? I came up with nothing on Google

Comment: See e.g. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wayland#SDL2

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered problems with the run zircon kernel of fucsia.

if you do the command

**./scripts/run-zircon-x86-64**

I get a mistake

I resolved to take it off

**-check,-fsgsbase**

from the flag

-cpu Haswell,+smap,-check,-fsgsbase

it must be a problem with my CPU

I did not want to start fuchsia but only the zircon kernel,
with this small change I can.
I do not know if it's your case

Comment: I don't see these flags in that script. anywhere else you might see it?

Comment: This wasn't the problem for me. Turns out, qemu won't play nice with Linux kernel anymore, as the kernel is moving towards Wayland